# swagger, actuator "Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: swagger, spring-boot-actuator

When using Spring Boot 2.6 actuator and swagger together, "Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException" error occurs.

The swagger bug was fixed by setting spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy.ant_path_matcher , but when actuator is added, the low error occurs again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem. It got solved when I downgraded the spring boot version from 2.6.3 to 2.4.1.
If there is mismatch between spring boot version and swagger version. Then this issue happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I opted to switch to spring rest docs instead of swagger